# face mask overlapping with border on spark ar studio

Tags: filter, spark-ar-studio

I've added a border on my filter and my face overlaps and it looks like my face is just floating over the border.

I've already tried changing the layers, and turning off the buttons in Advanced Render Options but still overlaps